# Why don't warnings generate errors?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In VS.NET 2012, I'd like an error to appear if no XML comments have been provided.  In the Build tab for my project, I added "Specific warnings" for CS1591 but no errors.  I then changed it to "All".  Still no errors.

Does anyone know what I need to set so missing XML comments will generate an error when building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have warnings as errors (either 'all warnings as errors' or `1591`), *and* have "XML Documentation File" selected for the build configuration you are using (if you want errors when compiling in debug, you must have xml docs generated in debug profile)

The specific warnings-as-errors list requires just the numbers, not the full code (i.e. `1591`, not `CS1591`)

Comment: Well, not necessarily *all* warnings as error - you can have *specific* warnings as errors.

Comment: Why if I specify warning CS1591 specifically it doesn't show an error?

Comment: JonSkeet - Of course, you are right. @4thSpace, try using just the number: `1591`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **#pragma** directive for this:

```
#pragma warning(error: 1591)
```

[Pragma directives: warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Where would this go since I want it to apply to all classes in the project and not just one area.